# node.js url of video id

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on new project.

and I'm trying to get the video id from the URL

the URL needs to be `"localhost/MyVid/Watch/xSw23PzA"`

`xSw23PzA` - is the id and I don't know how to get that.

I'm using `socket.io` to send data for the HTML file, and I have no idea how I can get the Video Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're always using the same schema

```
var url = "localhost/MyVid/Watch/xSw23PzA";
var videoId = url.split('/').pop();
```

Comment: For the record, you can also do it with a regular expression : `"localhost/MyVid/Watch/xSw23PzA".match(/[^\/]*$/)[0]`

Comment: Thanks it's work perfect, but there is any way to get the original URL with `socket.io`?